# printing pending background jobs from zsh

Tags: zsh

I am running background jobs and want to print pending jobs every time one finishes, but what get is

```
{ sleep 5; echo ""; jobs } &
[1] 147372
{ sleep 5; echo ""; jobs } &
[2] 147399
{ sleep 5; echo ""; jobs } &
[3] 147426
{ sleep 5; echo ""; jobs } &
[4] 147453
```

Then they finish by printing this

```
[1]    147372 done       { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }

[1]    running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[2]    147399 done       { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }

[1]    running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[2]  + running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[3]  - 147426 done       { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }

[1]    running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[2]  - running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[3]  + running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[4]  + 147453 done       { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
```

But I was expecting to see something like this:

```
[2]  - running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[3]  + running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[4]  + running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[1]    147372 done       { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }

[3]  + running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[4]  + running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[2]    147399 done       { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }

[4]  + running    { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
[3]  - 147426 done       { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }

[4]  + 147453 done       { sleep 5; echo ""; jobs; }
```

Seems like jobs is executed in the beginning not in the end of a sleep, is it possible to do that?

Comment: I can not reproduce this behaviour. For this test, I would also put a `date  +%H:%M:%S` directly before and after the `sleep`, to get a time stamp. This might help in analysis.

Comment: just realized I am in zsh, tried in bash with date before and after sleep and it gives the correct time but "jobs" prints nothing at all from background in bash it only prints if I type it myself

Comment: Interestingly, It seems to work for me in zsh as well. Your problem is interesting, so why not change it to a zsh question? Maybe someone comes up with a good explanation.

Comment: just realized another thing I am using oh-my-zsh :) maybe that is the source of the issue

Comment: The settings of oh-my-zsh are of course in effect, when you have an interactive shell (i.e. on the command line). If this were the culprit, doing things manually on the command line would show the wrong behaviour.

Comment: I would do the following: Pack the 4 lines which consist of your test, into a script, and run this script **explicitly** with zsh, bash and POSIX shell. While the `jobs` command is an internal command and therefore dependent on the shell you use, this should not matter for that simple example. If you have the possibility, repeat the test on different platforms (for instance, MacOS and Linux).